# How to efficiently count each element in a list in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, count

Suppose that we have the following list:

```
["aa", "abc", "aa", "bc", "abc", "abc", "a"]
```

I would like to get the following result about the occurrence of each element:
"abc": 3
"aa" 2
"a": 1
"bc": 1

What would the best way in this case?
The following is an approach I came up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

word_list = ["aa", "abc", "aa", "bc", "abc", "abc", "a"]

word_count_list = [[word, word_list.count(word)] for word in set(word_list)]
print (sorted(word_count_list, key = lambda word_count : word_count[1], reverse=True))
```

But I'm not quite sure whether the above approach is efficient. Could you suggest a good way for doing this?

Comment: The best way is to use `collections.Counter`.

Comment: counts = {}
for word in word_list:
            if word not in counts:
                counts[word] = 1
            else:
                counts[word] += 1

for word in counts:
    print(word, counts[word])